# Can certain distribution groups be restricted to the BCC field only?

Tags: exchange-2010

If a user sends an email with a large distribution group in the To or CC fields, often many recipients will use Reply To All and spam everyone with responses (such as: "Congrats").

The fix is to put the DG into the BCC field so that a mass reply is impossible.

I know that I can enforce this client side in Outlook with VBA but is there a way to restrict it server side?

Comment: Just a tip,putting large groups in BCC would break peoples filters. If thats an intended side effect, then I guess its fine.

Comment: Haven't thought about that but it would be an acceptable drawback.